# Finding gitlab.com/company/project/.vscode latest

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a go project with vscode, when I run debug with those settings:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env.local",
            "args": [],
        }
    ]
}
```

I get:

```
go: finding gitlab.com/company/project/.vscode latest
can't load package: package gitlab.com/company/project/.vscode: unknown import path "gitlab.com/company/project/.vscode": cannot find module providing package gitlab.com/company/project/.vscode
exit status 1
Process exiting with code: 1
```

What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Sounds like you're editing a file within your `.vscode` folder (e.g. the `launch.json` file you quoted) when you try to debug. Debug is relative to the file you have open (as you can see by the `${fileDirname}` in your config). If you only ever want to debug one binary in your project, you can override that setting to always point at that package.

Comment: I don't really understand what should I do. I expect vscode do a go build as he is currently doing, and then launch debug. Is is a way to print result of ${fileDirname} to check the content ?

Comment: As I said in the comment, just run debug with an actual Go file open instead of with your `launch.json` open.

Comment: ah ok, you are right, I could get rid of the error :) Thanks ! You can put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're editing a file within your .vscode folder (e.g. the launch.json file you quoted) when you try to debug. Debug is relative to the file you have open (as you can see by the `${fileDirname}` in your config). So the easiest fix is to make sure you have open the Go file you want to debug when you try to debug.

If you only ever want to debug one binary in your project, you can override the `program` setting in `launch.json` to always point at that package.